# Return type of the save() method

Tags: django, forms, save

I am a beginner trying to create registration forms using django. Here is the register view class which I had written earlier.

```
def register(request):

registered= False

if request.method=="POST":
    user_form= UserRegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form= UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        user_form.set_password(user_form.password)
        user_form.save()

        profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile_form.user=user_form

        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile_form.profile_pic=request.FILES('profile_pic')


        profile_form.save()

        registered=True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

else:
    user_form=UserRegistrationForm()
    profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()


return render(request,'basic_app/register.html',
              {'user_form':user_form,
               'profile_form':profile_form,
               'registered':registered})
```

The code gives me the error that my user_form object has no set_password() method.
I then changed my code by saving the "user_form" into another instance named "user". Here is my new code. I have added an additional print function to check the type of the two objects.

```
def register(request):

registered=False

if request.method=="POST":
    user_form=UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user=user_form.save()
        print(type(user_form),"   ",type(user))
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user=user

        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']

        profile.save()

        registered=True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)


else:
    user_form=UserForm()
    profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()


return render(request,'basic_app/register.html',
              {'user_form':user_form,
               'profile_form':profile_form,
               'registered':registered})
```

The output for the print statement gave this

```
<class 'basic_app.forms.UserRegistrationForm'>     <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
```

I do not understand howcome their type is different when both are instances of the same form. Also why did the first code didn't work when the second one did.

Its my first question on SO. Thank you.

Comment: *"I do not understand howcome their type is different when both are instances of the same form."* `user_form` is an instance of `UserRegistrationForm`. Whereas, if you do `user = user_form.save()`, the `user` variable is assigned the value returned by `save()` method, which happens to be an instance of the `User` model.

Comment: thank you, its more clear now.

Answer (score 8):

[`ModelForm.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) does not return an instance of `ModelForm`. It returns the instance of `Model` that was created/updated by the `ModelForm`.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.